# How can I script a simple SOAP server to return static XML based on namespace of incoming request?

Tags: ruby, xml, perl, soap, tcp

I need to do some testing for an application that makes multiple
SOAP calls to a third party application and then processes the result.
I wanted to send specific data to the application under test from a
program that simulates the third party application.

I realized that all I really needed was to have a server process that
1) accepts incoming SOAP calls from the application under test
2) determines what namespace is being used in the incoming SOAP call
3) returns a SOAP reponse using static XML based on that namespace.

I thought I'd simply use Ruby's SOAP::RPC::StandaloneServer, but that expects
a single namespace in the constructor, so I was stumped (I did consider
monkey-patching the code that handles namespaces, but that looked hard).
Then, I thought I'd try something with Ruby's TCPServer. I got as far as
the code below when I realized I had no idea how to correctly return the
appropriate XML in the correct SOAP fashion.

```
    require 'socket'

    server = TCPServer.new('127.0.0.1', 9800)
    loop {
      client = server.accept
      # This is for illustration only, it's clearly wrong
      while line = client.gets
        if line =~ /urn:foo/
          # return the foo xml in the correct SOAP fashion
        elsif line =~ /urn:bar/
          # return the bar xml in the correct SOAP fashion
        end
      end
      client.close
    }
    trap('INT') { exit }
```

Note that the application under test is not a Ruby application and it is
not friendly to testing. Also note that I'd happily consider another solution
(such as a Perl solution) if it was easier--I just started with Ruby since
I have a little bit of experience with it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this instead, it does pretty much exactly what you want. http://www.soapui.org/

Comment: Richard, thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, I need something scriptable. I'm essentially writing a load testing tool, but one that accepts data requests and returns data rather than trying to load a web server down. That is, the load is *pulled* back to the application under test, not pushed to it in typical load testing fashion. It's possible that a traditional load testing tool could accomplish what I need, but those tools have a fairly steep learning curve compared to what I actually am trying to accomplish, so that's why I was hoping to have a simple script.